# The importance of the Feynman Path Integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

For our middle school "Final Exhibition Paper" we had to choose a historical figure from a list to write a paper on, and I chose Richard Feynman. One of the requirements of the paper is to describe his major achievements in detail, which means describing the Feynman Path Integral.

In the last few weeks, I've tried to learn as much quantum mechanics as I can to form a basis of understanding this. What I've gotten so far is this:

In classical mechanics, a particle traveling from point $(x_0,t_0 )$ to point $(x',t' )$ has one trajectory, $x(t)$. In quantum mechanics, however, we cannot speak of a particle taking a trajectory from one point to another. We can only speak of the probability of a particle being at these two points, in reference to wave functions $|ψ(x_0,t_0)⟩$ and $|ψ(x',t')⟩$. Then, the probability amplitude of the particle going from $(x_0,t_0)$ to $(x',t')$ can be obtained from summing the probability amplitudes of every path in the space. And of course, there are explicit formulas to do just that, and approximations that become functional integrals as they approach $\infty$.

What I don't understand though, is why this makes any difference. Sure, it provides a (somewhat complicated) way to calculate one particle's probability of taking a path, but many lecture notes state boldy that it is possible to recover all of quantum mechanics from this definition. In fact, it's even called the "Path Integral Formulation of QM". But I've never seen the reasoning behind this. What makes this definition so fundamental that all other things can be recovered from this?

Comment: Well, you can recover the Scrodinger equation from path integral, I believe

Comment: @innisfree Do you have any reference or explanation for that? I would love to know about that. Thanks!